# How to access props.children with testing-library/no-node-access

Tags: eslint, react-props, children, testing-library

I have successfully installed [eslint-plugin-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library) and used `overrides` so it only warns me on code in test files.

However, it complains `Avoid direct Node access. Prefer using the methods from Testing Library.` for the following code `props.children`:

I want to be able to insert children, or a default node.

```
return (
  <>
    { // Other elements here. }
    {'children' in props ? (
      props.children
    ) : (
      <MyComponent {...props} disabled={disabled} />
    )}
  </>
)
```

What is wrong with this code? Why is props considered node access? How should I change it to satisfy the warning? Just add `// eslint-disable-next-line testing-library/no-node-access`?

`Edit:`

This is in a test file. It is creating an element in the same way as the main code. I do not understand why referencing `props.children` would warrant a warning. I wonder what is the justification for the warning and how else to perform the desired outcome.

Comment: This code is in a test file? What's the context?

Comment: This might be a case where you should just use `// eslint-disable-next-line testing-library/no-node-access`. Couple of questions though: why are you replicating the main code's functionality in your test? Is it a dependency? Wouldn't mocking it make more sense?

Comment: @juliomalves That is a good question. I was isolating a (slightly different) component for testing, but I think it would be better to export the component from the main code and import it in the test. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author of `eslint-plugin-testing-library` here! I'm sorry about this specific behavior being reported. Indeed, `props.children` is a valid usage and shouldn't be reported. Could you [report this as a new issue](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/issues/new)? We can take a look at improving this rule in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @mario. I have submitted a report.

Comment: I have the same problem but in a different scenario. I'm using an external component, that also uses Material UI, an Icon Button that has an svg and I want to see what icon class is rendered. I think using DOM methods as 'querySelector' is not a bad idea and should not be restricted by default

Comment: Querying elements by CSS classes is against the main principles of Testing Library. If you need to check if a certain element has a particular CSS class, I'd recommend querying it with provided Testing Library queries, and then using [`toHaveClass`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveclass) matcher.

Comment: @MarioBeltrán `expect(productTableTree.children.length).toBe(3)` So, getting the error for something like this is  to disregard? Just making sure that there isn't som e other equivalent method to use.

Comment: @CodeFinity that's actually the case the mentioned rule aims to prevent! You should query the children of your table tree, and then check there are 3 elements. Something like:


`const tableChildren = within(productTableTree).getAllByRole('row');
expect(tableChildren).toHaveLength(3)`

Comment: I figured. Tx. Actually, I am now better understanding the use case for Snapshots and `react-test-renderer`. If we create the Snapshot, we can just inspect for things like that visually and then forget about it unless/until the Snapshot fails. Meanwhile, we use the RTL to worry about UI interactions, clicks, etc.