# Avoid direct Node access. Prefer using the methods from Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-testing-library

I'm getting this error in eslint testing-library in React.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import Component from '.';

describe('Component testing', () => {
  test('Component', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Component>I am a message</Component>);

    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Reading this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099835/how-to-access-props-children-with-testing-library-no-node-access), I'm not quite sure what would be the real difference between accessing `container.children` and  `container.firstChild` or `container.children[0]`. Also how to solve this? It seems the library doesn't provide a real solution? https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-node-access.md

Comment: Did you see the examples of correct code for this rule and the `allowContainerFirstChild` option?

Comment: @LinDu Yeah that basically disables the rule, my point is to get to understand what is the point of this rule...

Answer (score 0):

This error was reported as a bug here https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-node-access.md

As a workaround you can use this approach.

```
describe('Component testing', () => {
  test('Component', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Component>I am a message</Component>);

    const {firstChild} = container 

    expect(firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```